# sample_weight not recognized in skgarden.quantile.RandomForestQuantileRegressor.fit()

Tags: python, scikit-learn

The documentation has sample_weight as an available parameter for RandomForestQuantileRegressor.fit(X, y) here: https://scikit-garden.github.io/api/#skgardenquantile_1 however it throws an error when trying to do this. It works for DecisionTreeQuantileRegressor but not for RandomForestQuantileRegressor. Is this intended?

example:

```
import numpy as np
import skgarden 

# we create 20 points
np.random.seed(0)
X = np.r_[np.random.randn(10, 2) + [1, 1], np.random.randn(10, 2)]
y = [1] * 10 + [-1] * 10
sample_weight_last_ten = abs(np.random.randn(len(X)))
sample_weight_constant = np.ones(len(X))
# and bigger weights to some outliers
sample_weight_last_ten[15:] *= 5
sample_weight_last_ten[9] *= 15

# fit the model WITH WEIGHTS
clf_weights = skgarden.DecisionTreeQuantileRegressor(random_state=0)
clf_weights.fit(X, y, sample_weight=sample_weight_last_ten)
```

trains properly but when trying this:

```
import numpy as np
import skgarden 

# we create 20 points
np.random.seed(0)
X = np.r_[np.random.randn(10, 2) + [1, 1], np.random.randn(10, 2)]
y = [1] * 10 + [-1] * 10
sample_weight_last_ten = abs(np.random.randn(len(X)))
sample_weight_constant = np.ones(len(X))
# and bigger weights to some outliers
sample_weight_last_ten[15:] *= 5
sample_weight_last_ten[9] *= 15

# fit the model WITH WEIGHTS
clf_weights = skgarden.quantile.RandomForestQuantileRegressor(random_state=0)
clf_weights.fit(X, y, sample_weight=sample_weight_last_ten)
```

This error pops up:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-375-dfda3c67445e> in <module>
     15 # fit the model WITH WEIGHTS
     16 clf_weights = skgarden.quantile.RandomForestQuantileRegressor(random_state=0)
---> 17 clf_weights.fit(X, y, sample_weight=sample_weight_last_ten)

TypeError: fit() got an unexpected keyword argument 'sample_weight'
```

What is another way that I can add weights to each sample when training?